# Is it possible to run SimCity on two monitors?

Tags: simcity-2013

I've seen the game [running on three monitors](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShM63fmfPfY), but I think that was with ATI's Eyefinity or Nvidia's Surround.

There are no options for it in the settings menu, but the description of the video says the game has "native multi-monitor support", and the home screen even demonstrates this by revealing the city to be a prop:
[image: SimCity's multi-monitor homescreen]

So is there some way to do it with just two?

Comment: You'll have to configure your video card to only use two. When in multi-monitor spanning modes, games can't choose what video settings to use, it's controlled by the video card.

Comment: this interests me. I will look in to this too when I get a chance. 2 x 24" is a lot cheaper than 1 x 30". Wider too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nvidia Surround**: You cannot run with two monitors, you must use 3 monitors.

**ATI eyefinity**: You can use two monitors, however, users reported that it was very annoying because the center of the screen was the border of the 2 monitors. They strongly recommended 3 monitors so this would not occur.

There are YouTube videos demonstrating how to set these up.

*Not being able to try either of these (for technical reasons regardless of the 4 monitors I am staring at),* this is the best answer I can give.

**Alternatives**
If you are after more real estate for playing, there are 27" and 30" monitors that support larger resolutions of 2560 wide.

Dell has an ultrawide 29" which is the same resolution width as the 30", just not as high. The price is up to 1/4 of the price of the 30". It is worth a look.

Because you may have to get an additional graphics card to support 3 monitors, a larger monitor could be the cost effective solution.

Comment: I just saw the 2560x1080 screens a few days after getting a second monitor :(

Comment: i was considering it too until the marriage intervened.

Answer (score 3):

SimCity does not have native multi-monitor support, so will not utilise two or more screens without the use of third party technologies like Eyefinity or Nvidia surround (or equivalent technologies or devices) to allow the use of ultra wide (or ultra high, depending on the orientation of your monitors) resolutions.